# 2D texture mapping

Tags: python, texture-mapping

I have a project I am working on where I want to take a sheet of images and map them onto a rendered model.
[image: Example image]

To try and achieve this I have so far done the following:

- Used opencv to isolate the items from a sheet of textures, using mahotas to identify which part of the texture is which
  [image]
- Created a binary mask of this image and extracted contours, convex hull, corners etc all using opencv as this was information I thought would be useful
  [image]
- Created a binary mask from the image of the bike of the area I want the texture object to fit, I did this manually in photoshop (this is not a problem to do manually)
  [image]

The problem I am having is then taking that information and mapping one to the other:
[image]

For example mapping this red texture to the black shape which represents the texture shape on the bike. I know I need to use affine transform or similar and so I have tried using the points retrieved by contouring each mask, however, this obviously returns different numbers of points between the texture and reference shape so the transformation isnt possible. Is this even possible??

Comment: I don't understand the initial problem. Do you have the bike's mesh (vertices, UV, etc)? Or do you recognize the parts from a rendered bike image?

Comment: It is just an image not a 3d model, so no I dont have vertices etc, I recognise the parts by taking each one and comparing it to a set of "standard" parts, i.e. I take the mahotas shape descriptor of each part and compare it to a test part to figure out which part it is, I then have a set of standard shapes as shown in black in the above red and black image. I take the recognised part and its equivalent standard shape and I am trying to warp one to the other. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: My machine learning background would tell me to build a neural net, feeding it the red shape, and comparing the output with the black shape (L2 norm, maybe Earth's mover distance, maybe some more). After not so long optimization (hopefully about minute) it may start giving good waprings. About an algorithmic approach, I can't think of a single one...

Comment: Machine learning seems like a great approach but I wouldn't even know where to start on that, are there some places you can send me to learn? My only experience in neural nets is building one simple classifier once!!

Comment: I'll try to explain in more details. You compose a dataset, basically pairs of input OpenCV mask and output desired mask, for all the bikes and bikes parts you have. You take a backbone - some **pretrained** image neural net ([examples](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html), such backbone has already seen millions of photos, so it's likely that it has learnt notion of shapes, curves (even color) very well. ...

Comment: Many backbones come with a final layer that is a classifier. Since our task is different, in Python you remove a few last layers, and replace them with your custom ones, that return an image in the end (e.g. a few convolutional layers). Next we "unfreeze" about half of last layers (it's different in different frameworks, e.g. [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html), this will make the backbone to "fine tune" itself to the data we want. Some backbones require specific resolution of input images (e.g. about 221x221px), change data accordingly

Comment: Next the optimization loop, the link above shows how it's done in PyTorch, split the data in train/test, feed whole train, check performance on test. The most creative part is choosing loss functions, that's up to you, can start with L2, if net doesn't learn anything, add some other (google something around "warping loss" or "image to image loss")

Comment: Would this be appropriate in your opinion? https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/spatial_transformer_tutorial.html

Comment: Looks like a good starting point. Making it working would require a clever combination of loss functions. In general any architectrue is up to experimentation, research, with no guarantee of success

Comment: Atleast their variant trains for 2 minutes for the whole dataset, not hours

Comment: One day I'll learn machine learning properly! Thanks you for all your help though